# Symfony validation accept wrong mime-type application/postscript

Tags: validation, symfony, mime-types

I'm currently working on a basic form on symfony 2.8. 
The user can upload a File through a classic filetype.

I'm using symfony validation assert to validate the mime-type of the object sent by the user : it should be only pdf or doc files. It's working great, it does not validate images for exemple.

BUT it's still possible to upload adobe illustrator file. The mime-type *application/postscript* is accepted by the validation process. I can't figure why. Do you have an idea?

My entity class :

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_candidature_file")
 */
class CandidatureFile extends AbstractFile
{
    /**
     * @var UploadedFile
     *
     * @Assert\File(
     *     maxSize="3500000",
     *     mimeTypes = {"application/pdf", "application/x-pdf", "application/msword", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"},
     *     mimeTypesMessage = "app.candidature_file.file.mime_types_message"
     * )
     */
    protected $file;
}
```

I should specify that I'm using cascade validation in the form.

Thank you in advance if you have an idea.